# Sending credentials for every database request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, request

I'm building a web application whereby a user logs in with a  username and password that is stored on the same server database as the application data. AJAX calls are made to pull data from the server.

How are sessions typically maintained when a user logs in? Should I be sending the user credentials (a hashed password, of course) in every AJAX request? I'm guessing that the responsibility here lies with the server-side scripts and not the DB for a lot of this?

I'm fairly new to HTML5, JavaScript, jQuery and so on but I'm picking it up fast. So hopefully there's a nice solution for this!

Cheers folks!

Answer (score 0):

The user session should be maintained on the server. There is no need to pass user credentials  with each AJAX call. All you would be doing is pass the user info from the server to the front end and then back to the server. This will expose unnecessary risk.

You should do perform a user check on the server with each call.